# CSS - making multiple children the height of the tallest child

Tags: html, css

How do I make both of the fieldsets be the height of the tallest one? Here's the code, which can also be seen at http://jsfiddle.net/zpcXQ/2/

```
<div id="parent">

  <form>
    <fieldset id="left">
        <legend>Left</legend>
        <p>line 1</p>
        <p>line 2</p>
        <p>line 3</p>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset id="right">
        <legend>Right</legend>
        <p>line 1</p>
    </fieldset>
  </form>

</div>
```

---

```
fieldset {
    border: 1px solid green;
    width: 48%;
    position: relative;
}

#parent {
    float: left;
    width: 600px;
    position: relative;
}

#left {
    float: left;
}

#right {
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: Possible dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7855747/how-to-make-three-columns-the-same-height, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168573/same-height-of-columns-with-960-gs, more. I suppose people keep asking this because there's no great, canonical solution. I like the faux-columns approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using jquery as following:

```
var fieldSets = $("fieldset").toArray();
var highest = 0;
for(var i=0; i< fieldSets.length; i++){
    var tempHeight = $(fieldSets[i]).height();
    if(tempHeight > highest){
        highest = tempHeight;
    }
}
$("fieldset").height(highest);
```